# Cleartext HTTP traffic to myserver.com not permitted on Android N preview

Tags: android, http, https

Yesterday I got a new upgrade for the Android N preview. Ever since I upgraded, I cannot start my app anymore.

```
java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to myserver.com not permitted
```

I have tried to set the `usesCleartextTraffic` to `true` in the manifest or to add a `network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">myserver.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Neither did work. Any ideas about what is going on there?

When I try to define networkSecurityConfig in the manifest, I get a compile error

```
Error:(35) No resource identifier found for attribute 'networkSecurityConfig' in package 'android'
```

Not really sure why. The file is there and everything looks good.

Found [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=212584) suggestion in the Android issue tracker from Google. They suggest to move the `network_security_config` definition to the `meta-data`. I still get the same exception though.

Comment: Just to be sure, you actually told your app to use the config file? e.g. `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` in your application manifest.

Comment: I do not seem to have this problem, at least in the app I just tested. Plaintext HTTP traffic is fine. You might try a full uninstall and reinstall of the app. Also, are you using `StrictMode`? Perhaps [`detectCleartextNetwork()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder.html#detectCleartextNetwork()) is being turned on

Comment: I uninstalled and re-installed several times already and I am not using StrictMode. I am not able though to define the networkSecurityConfig in the manifest. I'll update the question

Comment: Are you using OKHttp?

Comment: "When I try to define networkSecurityConfig in the manifest, I get a compile error" -- move to `compileSdkVersion 24` and `buildSdkTools "24.0.0"`.

Comment: In addition to adding the network_security_config file, did you link it in your manifest as "<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
               ... >"
?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a known issue in Android N Developer Preview 4 where, if an app modifies its `ApplicationInfo.flags`, it triggers the blocking of cleartext traffic from the app, even if the app didn't request cleartext traffic to be blocked. The fix is in the next Developer Preview. Thus, this has nothing to do with your Network Security Config. In fact, it looks like you don't even need to declare a custom Network Security Config.

If you can't wait until the next Android N Developer Preview, check your app for places where it modifies its own `ApplicationInfo.flags`. Typically this takes the form of `getApplicationInfo().flags &= ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` or `getApplicationInfo().flags = ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE`. The fix for these usages is `(getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE)`.

Alternatively, as a workaround, invoke `NetworkSecurityPolicy.isCleartextTrafficPermitted()` as early in your app's lifecycle as possible. This workaround should work if invoked before the code which tampers with `ApplicationInfo.flags`.

Comment: Just curious, did you find that your app was accidentally modifying its `ApplicationInfo.flags`?

Comment: Yes it was. We used a `&=` for a check instead of a simple `&`

Comment: From Android P we need to specify custom Network Security Config which has cleartextTrafficPermitted=true, check Security Behavior Changes - https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-behav#tls-enabled

Answer (score 19):

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

put this line in application tag in manifest file

Answer (score 5):

**Try just one line in your Application Tag**

> android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
       ...
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       ...>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"

    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">

    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Comment: thanks!! that fixed it for me, adding the trust-anchors in to the network_security_config.xml.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
       ...
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       ...>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

This one worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: YOU SAVED MY WEEK

Answer (score 1):

From API level 28 onwards the `usesCleartextTraffic` is disabled by  default. So, If you want to enable it, then set the `usesCleartextTraffic` as true in the androidManifest file like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
       ...
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       ...>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a XML res/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Reference this file in your tag Application, inside AndroidManifest.xml. Like:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I made here is the following code should be inside the manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: This needs to be updated in the manifest file under the application tag. Works perfectly for me.